# Accessing GCP VMS from AWS API Gateway

Tags: google-cloud-platform, aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc, google-vpc

I want to access Rest APIs hosted in Google cloud VMs, and I am using AWS API Gateway for authorising the requests using Lambda Authorizer.
What are the ways I can use so that my purpose is served.

I already tried using VPC link, which didn't work.

Comment: Which security do you expect? What are the other requirements?

Comment: How is the API on the GCP VM's exposed? How is the AWS API Gateway gonna reach the API on GCP ? Do you have a VPN between the two clouds or ill your expose the GCP VM's behind a Public LoadBalancer and use that as a backend to the AWS API Gateway